# Angular toggling content display issue

Tags: jquery, angularjs, toggle, angularjs-ng-repeat, slidetoggle

I am working on a mobile web app in AngularJS and I am stuck on a problem involving hidden content I want to toggle.

```
<div class="results row animated fadeInUp">

    <p class="center" ng-hide="tips_list">{{ 'NORESULTS' | translate }}</p>

    <ul class="list list-slideout small-12 columns">
        <li class="list-item" ng-style="speciesColor" ng-repeat="tip in tips_list | orderBy:'title' | filter:searchFilter" >
            <h2>{{ tip.title }}</h2>
            <div class="list-item-content" ng-bind-html="tip.body">
                {{ tip.body }}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

The above code block shows my HTML view. As you can see, the data is loaded dynamically using ng-repeat. '.list-item-content' has 'display:none' as attribute and when you click/tap on the parent '.list-item' it will show the content, which is what the below code in my controller does.

```
$(document).on("click", ".tips .list-item", function() {

        $(this).children(".list-item-content").slideToggle();
        //$(this).children(".list-item-content").stop(true).slideToggle();

        // scroll to top of clicked element with fast animation
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 400);
    });
```

I am using jQuery for this and I also wanted to add a slideOut animation so I used slideToggle. I also scroll to the top of the parent element to make it easier for users to read the content (removing this does not fix my problem).

Now the problem is that when I click/tap on the list item it sometimes slides back up after sliding down, making it impossible to view the content. This is always fixed on reloading the page, but when going to a different page with a similar layout I usually have the same problem.

**Things I have tried:**

- Adding '.stop(true)' to the slideOut function. All this did was change the problem from 'sliding back up' to 'not sliding at all'
- Using regular toggles without animations. Same problem as above.
- Using classToggle with a 'hidden'class and with both a 'hidden' and 'shown' class
- Manually checking the display attribute on the element and then changing the css appropriately using the .css() function.
- Removing the fadein animation on the parent div (didn't do anything)

When I check the element using Chrome developer tools, I notice that he briefly changes the inline style to 'display:block' but then immediately reverts back to 'display:none'.

I had trouble finding any posts with exactly this problem, so if I missed a similar post (probably because I didn't search on the right terms) please let me know.

This is my first question on Stackoverflow, just wanted to let you know that this site has helped me a lot in the past (Here's hoping the community will help me again).

**TL:DR : problem with toggling display (using jQuery) on generated content in AngularJS**

Comment: Can you set up a Plunker?

Comment: I have no experience setting up a Plunker/jsfiddle etc. & it seems pretty tricky to try and set it up exactly like my project. If there's a specific question, I'll be glad to answer though.

Comment: Just a lot easier for people to help when they can try and experiment with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by replacing the on("click") function with angular ng-click.

**Updated view:**

```
<div class="results row animated fadeInUp">

    <p class="center" ng-hide="tips_list">{{ 'NORESULTS' | translate }}</p>

    <ul class="list list-slideout small-12 columns">
        <li class="list-item" ng-style="speciesColor" ng-repeat="tip in tips_list | orderBy:'title' | filter:searchFilter" ng-click="showContent($index)" id="item-{{$index}}">
            <h2>{{ tip.title }}</h2>
            <div class="list-item-content" ng-bind-html="tip.body">
                {{ tip.body }}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**Updated controller function**

```
$scope.showContent = function(id){

        var elementToShow = '#item-' + id;

        $(elementToShow).children(".list-item-content").slideToggle();

        // scroll to top of clicked element with fast animation
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(elementToShow).offset().top
        }, 400);

    }
```

Instead of getting the child of the clicked item, I added unique id's to the printed items using the angular "$index" variable.

I still use a jQuery slideToggle function, but now the bug (where the items stay stuck in "display:none" is gone.

Apparently there must be some problem with jQuery click events on printed ng-repeat elements.

Let me know if this question is relevant enough to stay on here, maybe some people can comment further on this problem and improve this answer.